# How to repartition a dataframe based on more than one column?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe: yearDF with the following columns: `name, id_number, location, source_system_name, period_year`.

If I want to repartition the dataframe based on a column, I'd do:

```
yearDF.repartition('source_system_name')
```

I have a variable: `val partition_columns = "source_system_name,period_year"`

I tried to do it this way:

```
val dataDFPart = yearDF.repartition(col(${prtn_String_columns}))
```

but I get a compilation error: `cannot resolve the symbol $`

Is there anyway I can repartition the dataframe: `yearDF` based on the values in `partition_columns`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three implementations of the repartition function in Scala / Spark :

```
def repartition(partitionExprs: Column*): Dataset[T]
def repartition(numPartitions: Int, partitionExprs: Column*): Dataset[T]
def repartition(numPartitions: Int): Dataset[T]
```

So in order to repartition on multiple columns, you can try to split your field by the comma and use the vararg operator of Scala on it, like this :

```
val columns = partition_columns.split(",").map(x => col(x))
yearDF.repartition(columns: _*)
```

Another way to do it, is to call every col one by one :

```
yearDF.repartition(col("source_system_name"), col("period_year"))
```

Comment: I tried the vararg method and it says: Type mismatch, expected: Seq[Column], actual: Array[String